# Remapping CapsLock+IJKY as cursor keys in VT without X running in Debian

Tags: shell, console, debian, customization, remap

On a GNU Debian Jessie system working under X, I successfully remapped a CapsLock key to function as Mode_switch in a file that is used by xmodmap.

Now with some extra remappings, when the CapsLock is pressed I'm able to use the IJKY keys as cursor keys, U/O as PageUP/PageDown.

Here's the content of that file:

```
keycode 66 = Mode_switch
keysym j = j J Left
keysym l = l L Right
keysym k = k K Down
keysym i = i I Up
keysym u = u U Page_Up
keysym o = o O Page_Down
```

It works fine and feels pretty comfortable as my hands do not have to travel around the keyboard (especially useful for navigating in VIM while in Command Mode).

Now here is the question:
Is there any similar hack I can do to make it work in
virtual console without X running?

Meanwhile I'm using  loadkeys for remapping, 
but I couldn't find anything similar to Mode_switch
there.